# Remove part of string after ## using php?

Tags: php, regex

I have a file which has many lines containing ##. I want to remove the part of string after ##.

Here is what I have tried

```
<?php
$file = fopen("testr.txt", "r");

$NewLineExplode = explode(PHP_EOL,$file);

$NewString      = '';
foreach($NewLineExplode  as $eachLine) {
$HashExlode = explode('##',$eachLine);
$NewString .= $HashExlode[0].'<br>';
 }

  echo $NewString;

 ?>
```

testr.txt look like this

```
citycredits.ru##.widget_banner
anvidelabs.org##.widget_banners
hcpeople.ru##.widget_board_ads
newsoboz.org##.widget_center > noindex
softolet.ru##.widget_custom_html
edurusnews.ru##.widget_execphp
poznamka.ru##.widget_hja_adsense
softolet.ru##.widget_media_image
yuzhny.info##.widget_media_image > img[width="360"][height="520"]
```

The output should be like this

```
citycredits.ru
anvidelabs.org
hcpeople.ru
newsoboz.org
softolet.ru
```

Comment: You are trying to “explode” a file pointer, which makes no sense. You neglected to actually _read_ the data from the file.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? It should not be too hard to debug the given code to check upon which line it works as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $string = fopen("testr.txt", "r");
    $NewString      = '';
    // Output one line until end-of-file
    while(!feof($string)) {
        $HashExlode = explode('##',fgets($string));
        $NewString .= $HashExlode[0].'<br>';
    }

    echo $NewString;
    fclose($string);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `preg_replace` here:

```
$file = fopen("testr.txt", "r");
$firstLine = true;
$NewString = "";

while(!feof($file))  {
    $eachLine = fgets($fn);
    $eachLine = preg_replace("/##.*$/", "", $eachLine);
    if (!firstLine) {
        $NewString .= '<br>';
    }
    else {
        firstLine = false;
    }
    $NewString .= '<br>';
}

echo $NewString;

fclose($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed few lines. Can try with this code.

```
<?php
    $file = fopen('testr.txt', "r");
    while (!feof($file) ) {
      $line_of_text = fgets($file);
      $NewLineExplode = explode(PHP_EOL, $line_of_text);
 
      $NewString      = '';
      foreach ($NewLineExplode  as $eachLine) {
        $HashExlode = explode('##',$eachLine);
        $NewString .= $HashExlode[0].'<br>';
      }
      echo $NewString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it without loops:

```
$inputFile = 'testr.txt';
$outputFile = 'testr2.txt';

file_put_contents($outputFile, preg_replace('~##.*$~m','',file_get_contents($inputFile)));
```

Comment: please help me with this question. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64081641/add-div-tag-inside-all-li-with-matching-class-name-using-php/64092865#64092865

Answer (score 0):

```
$filePath = 'testr.txt';
$file = fopen($filePath, 'r');
if ($file) {
    $text = fread($file, filesize($filePath));
    $lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $text);
    $result = '';

    foreach ($lines as $line) {
       $result .= substr($line, 0, strpos($line, '##'));
    }
    echo $result;
}
```